# Docker containerization. accessing container from other machine using container name instead of host IP

Tags: docker, docker-container

my client and server hosted in a Linux host using docker as container. From other machine of same network able to connect using host IP address but I am not able to connect using container name or container IP address. I want to call a API of my server side application using container name or IP not using host machine IP

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

The (Docker) container runtime(s) are entirely distinct; there's no shared state that would permit the container on one host to be able to enumerate the container names on another host.

The easiest way for you to connect a client container on one host with a server container on another host is publish the server containers' ports to the host and to leverage the (shared) networking between the client and server and use either the server host's name or IP address to access it from the client.

Comment: Can I edit a file of docker image during container creation?